# Pass a Variable Name to the Arguments of a Function (Python 3, Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say I have a DF defined as variable DF1:

```
  Words         Score
  The man        10
  A Plan         20
  Panama         30
```

And say I have a function:

```
def func(w, df):
   pattern = re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if pattern.search(df):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

How do I pass each row of DF1, specifically the columns 'Words', to the argument within the function?

EDIT: Ubuntu's answer is what I would normally use but I need to self reference the DF in my function

Comment: Ok, edited -- but how can I pass my DF to the function!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the `Series.apply` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply):

```
df1['Words'].apply(func)
```

If you wish to pass more positional arguments to `func`, use the `args` keyword parameter:

```
df1['Words'].apply(func, args=(df,))
```

or, to pass `df` as a keyword argument:

```
df1['Words'].apply(func, df=df)
```

since, [per the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply), *"[a]dditional keyword arguments [to `apply`] will be passed as keywords to the function"*.

Comment: @DSM: Your answer is more complete than mine; shall we swap delete states?

Comment: hmmm this gets me sort of the way here but not quite -- how can I apply that if I need to actually CALL the dataframe in the arguement?  Edited OP above

Comment: so if the function was to see whether a word (i.e. the w argument in the function) was found within df1['Words'] -- is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi Unutbu -- would you mind explaining a little bit more about this?  Unfamiliar with how this works.  What exactly is df=df representing?  Say I wanted to use this method is it called like this:  df1['Words'].apply(func('panama'), df1=df1)

Comment: This is an example of [passing keyword arguments to a function](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).